# Shell: Is there any way to avoid rsh to clean printf buffer?

Tags: printf, sh

I want to perform some sequence of entries in a script. In my script, I use a rsh and its use cleans the printf buffer.

I'd use 2 scripts. One script is like this: **test1.sh**

```
VAL=""
while [ "${VAL}" != "x" ]
do
    read VAL
    echo $VAL
done
```

Other script is like this: **test2.sh**

```
VAL=""
while [ "${VAL}" != "x" ]
do
    read VAL
    rsh -l user 172.30.7.157 "echo test"
    echo $VAL
done
```

When I execute *printf "12\n34\nx | test1.sh*, the result is:

```
12
34
x
```

When I execute *printf "12\n34\nx | test2.sh*, the result is:

```
12
teste

teste

teste

.
.
.
```

Which makes me think that using a remote connection cleans the CIOBUF.

Is there any way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a buffering issue; `rsh` is consuming the input meant for `read`. Redirection its standard input from `/dev/null`. (Also, you can just test the exit status of `read`, rather than messing around with comparing `VAL` to a sentinel value.)

```
while IFS= read -r val; do
do
    rsh -l user 172.30.7.157 "echo test" < /dev/null
    echo "$val"
done
```